# Split html string by tags without losing split character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I split a string like

```
var htmlstring = "<html><body><div><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div></body> </html>"
var output=htmlstring.split(solution);

// output should be 

[ "<html><body><div><p>", "this is", "<span>", "example", "</span>", "text", "</p></div></body> </html>"]
```

The solution should work for any string of html no matter how long or complicated it is

Solution does not have to be regex that is just what I have used so far

Any function that is better is fine as well

I know match() can be used

Have found regex to separate without losing seperator using dummy variable in replace function but does not separate the plain text into separate indexes

I have it now in separated by tags and text

Comment: I might do something like this `$('"<html><body><div><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div></bod y> </html>"').text().split(' ')` if you just wanted the words.  Else we get close to the obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: As this [legendary post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5019769) details, regex might not be the technique you wish to use here. If you want specific help on your issue, however, you need to at least share what regex you are trying to use.

Comment: Using regex it is not possible to _extract_ information from html tags (in other words _parse_). But surely, you can use it to do simple operations like separating the tags from the text like what you have asked for.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works using regex

https://fiddle.jshell.net/j5wz0rug/